SRGAN Android Tensorflow Lite inference output doesnt match to Python version
I was trying to implement Android Kotlin app with this model's tflite version, https://github.com/krasserm/super-resolution/blob/master
I have a gan_generator.tflite model. I can inference it and get correct output in Python with it. But I cant get same result as a bitmap in Android Kotlin even I made a same post-processing operations. Where did I missing?
from model.srgan import generator
from utils import load_image, plot_sample
from model import resolve_single
import tensorflow as tf


model = generator()
model.load_weights('weights/srgan/gan_generator.h5')


# Create a TFLite converter from the Keras model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)

# Set conversion parameters (optional)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT] 
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.float32]


# Convert the model
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the TFLite model to a file
with open('gan_generator.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='gan_generator.tflite')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()


input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']

input_data = np.asarray(load_image('demo/0869x4-crop.png'), dtype=np.float32)
input_data = np.expand_dims(input_data, axis=0)
input_data = np.reshape(input_data, (1, input_data.shape[1], input_data.shape[2], 3))

# Set the input tensor
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], (1, input_data.shape[1], input_data.shape[2], 3),strict=True)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()


interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# Get the output
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

output_data = np.squeeze(output_data)
output_data = np.clip(output_data, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

# Create a PIL Image from the NumPy array
image = Image.fromarray(output_data)
image  #output image created here successfully

###----------Android Side-------------------------
 val tensorImage = TensorImage(INPUT_IMAGE_TYPE).also { it.load(inputBitmap) }
            val processedImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage)

            //[1,4X,4X,3] Output
            val outputBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(
                intArrayOf(
                    1,
                    processedImage.width * outputShapeForScaling,
                    processedImage.height * outputShapeForScaling,
                    3
                ),
                OUTPUT_IMAGE_TYPE
            )
             
            // [1, None, None, 3] dynamic input
            interpreter!!.resizeInput(
                interpreter!!.getInputTensor(0).index(),
                intArrayOf(1, processedImage.width, processedImage.height, 3)
            )

            interpreter!!.allocateTensors()


            interpreter!!.run(processedImage.buffer, outputBuffer.buffer)

            val processedOutput = processOutput(
                outputBuffer,
                width = processedImage.width * 4,
                height = processedImage.height * 4
            )


##---------Post Process---------------------------
private fun processOutput(outputBuffer: TensorBuffer, width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap {
        val data = outputBuffer.floatArray

        // Check that the float array has the correct number of elements
        if (data.size != width * height * 3) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Data size does not match the expected image size.")
        }

        // Create an empty Bitmap
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

        // Iterate through the float array and set pixels in the bitmap
        var index: Int
        for (y in 0 until height) {
            for (x in 0 until width) {
                index = (y * width + x) * 3
                // Extract RGB values from the float array
                val r = data[index].coerceIn(0f, 255f).toInt()
                val g = data[index + 1].coerceIn(0f, 255f).toInt()
                val b = data[index + 2].coerceIn(0f, 255f).toInt()

                // Set the pixel color (we set alpha to 255 for full opacity)
                bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(r, g, b))
            }
        }

        return bitmap
    }

Result:

